# EE control panel pages take 10min to load

Tags: ee2

We have an EE v2.5 site that has been running fine for years. Now over the past few months accessing the control panel has gotten slower and slower. The site still works fine it is only the control panel that is slow. It can take up to 10min for the control panel to respond to logging in or any other page on the control panel site. I have tried disabling all extensions by setting `$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';` in the expressionengine/config/config.php file, but this did not seem to make a difference. I also optimized the MySQL databases. The servers get very little traffic (few hundred page loads a day). The web and database servers each have plenty of hardware resources (4 cores/4GB ram) and plenty of disk space. Any idea what the issue might be? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried turning off New Version Auto Check under General Configuration?

Comment: Yes. Had no effect. I also tried turning off HTTP headers. I uninstalled the ExpressionEngine Info accessory addon. Those also had no effect.

Comment: I also optimized the MySQL databases, with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly an issue with your server. Have you contacted your host? They should be able to shed some light on the issue. There has to be a bottleneck somewhere, and an experienced db admin should be able to get to the bottom of this by checking logs and configs.

Also, here's a related thread that might include a few useful pointers: [Slow control panel js and css loads](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4848/slow-control-panel-js-and-css-loads)

Comment: It might be some sort of configuration issue with the server, but its definitely not a resource issue with the server (ram, cpu, disk). This is on my own Vmware server and SAN, that only has a few other VMs on it. Nothing is putting any load on the VMWare server or the EE web or EE database servers.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking configuration as well.